# unable to access an array in object even though i can see it when using console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have two objects blackjack.player and blackjack.dealer.
when I console out either object I basically get the same reply in the console for both objects.
 My **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o85ppzge/)**

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
p:  Player {name: "Travis", currency: 0, cards: Array(2), points: 17, turn: false…}

p:  Dealer {name: "Dealer", cards: Array(2), cardsShowing: Array(0), points: 0, turn: false…}
```

when i use console.log(blackjack.player.cards)
I get the array of cards in the player's object.
But when i console.log(blackjack.dealer.cards)
I get an error in the console saying "Cannot read property 'cards' of undefined"

I am completely lost on why I am unable to access the properties of an object when I can see them in the console and can access an object with the same properties with no problem.

Comment: You're adding `blackjack.dealer` later in the code, the console.log happens when there is no `dealer` property.

Comment: Don't trust the `console.log` to reflect what is in the object *at the time of logging*, since only the object reference is logged. The actual content is retrieved asynchronously.